# How can I autostart a SSH -D tunnel at login for a SOCKS proxy?

Tags: ssh, startup, proxy, tunnel

I know that if I want to start an SSH tunnel

```
ssh -d 9000 user@userserver
```

This is one solution for a dynamic tunnel to be opened on port 9000 for a user named "user" on the host "userserver"

However, how can I automate this process in Ubuntu so that I don't have to open up a terminal every time I log in and start the tunnel? I want to be SSH'd the moment I log in.

I know I could create a bash file but wouldn't I have to store my server user's password in plaintext as I would be prompted for it after the initial command?

Comment: you can setup ssh-keys instead of using a password (see http://pkeck.myweb.uga.edu/ssh/ ), but no matter how your setup is you will be compromising security if you automate login's...

Comment: Not exactly about your question, but I recommend you try using [`sshuttle`](http://askubuntu.com/questions/45075/how-do-i-route-my-internet-through-a-ssh-tunnel/45110#45110) for routing your internet through a SSH. It doesn't solve password-less login issues.

Comment: If you set up password-less SSH as I answered, `sshuttle` can also be autostarted (note, `sshuttle` requires admin privileges to run).

Answer (score 9):

1. Set up password-less SSH login [according to this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46930/how-can-i-login-password-less-using-ssh/46935#46935):

   - `ssh-keygen` (you will be prompted for a password, leave it blank)
   - `ssh-copy-id user@userserver` (enter your SSH login password for the last time)
2. Add an startup entry for SSH:

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Stefano, thank you! Half the credit goes to Rinzwind and Marco who enlightened me about password-less SSH in the first place!

Answer (score 1):

How about using an ssh-key setup, as Source Lab suggested, but setting up your key with a pass phrase and make sure ssh-agent is running on your machine so it only needs to be entered once per login session.

There's a few advantages doing it that way:
 - You can get automated password-less login (apart from first boot/login) whenever you issue your ssh command
 - Your key has a pass phrase so it's safer
 - Using pub/private keys is very standard and will be supported by most SSH Server installations

To set up SSH key authentication:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys

To use ssh-agent/keychain (to cache the pass-phrase throughout the login session):

- http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ssh-passwordless-login-with-keychain-for-scripts/

As far as automating the tunnel creation on startup, one idea might be to create a quick shell script which starts the tunnel:

```
~$ sudo cat <<EOF >> /usr/local/bin/start_tunnel.sh
ssh-add # ensure key is added to agent
ssh -D 9000 user@userserver # substitute real server in here (of course)
EOF
~$ chmod +x /usr/local/bin/start_tunnel.sh
```

Then add it as a startup program (System -> Preferences -> Startup Applications), should work, anyway!

Comment: Is there anyway to do this via the network proxy section of the settings in Ubuntu? There is an option for user verification and you can pre-input your username and password? Just in case my settings ever change I wouldn't want to have to go in and redit the file.

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't work, not even with autossh.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a little script for just this: https://github.com/PHLAK/Soxy

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo ssh-keygen #type Enter everywhere
sudo cat /home/root/.ssh/ id_dsa.pub >> .ssh/authorized_keys
```

**/etc/rc.local** add string:

```
echo "ssh socks 192.168.0.1:8000" ; sudo ssh -fND 192.168.0.1:8000 localhost
```

Comment: Please bear in mind that the set up of a ssh key is dedicated. Blindly accepting all the prompts without reading what is being done could compromise your service/system.