# How do I route my internet through a SSH tunnel?

Tags: networking, ssh, tunnel

**Old Q** How do I setup an OpenVPN server without root privileges?

Is there a way to setup an OpenVPN server without root privileges? E.g. with configuration files in my home directory? If yes, how do I set it up?

I'm trying to SSH into a system and set up an OpenVPN server over there for personal use.

**EDIT**

Since it's apparent that OpenVPN needs root privileges, I am changing the question to routing my internet using SSH which I can easily set up.

Comment: By "userspace", do you mean in a home folder without root permissions? Usually, "userspace" is used as the opposite of "kernel space".

Comment: You might be interested in my answer on [How do I setup OpenVPN so I can securely use the internet from an unsecured hotspot?](http://askubuntu.com/q/35647/6969)

Comment: @Lekensteyn, yes without root permission, I did not know user-space referred to something else. Please feel free to edit my question into something appropriate. I was thinking of that answer as well, but I don't know about setting things up without root privileges.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

*[sshuttle](https://github.com/apenwarr/sshuttle/)* is a transparent proxy server that forwards over a SSH connection and sets up a proxy by running Python scripts on the remote server. `sshuttle` can be run under the following conditions:

- client machine or router is Linux-based, FreeBSD or Mac OS
- administrative privileges on client
- access to remote network via SSH
- **no** administrator privileges on remote network
- availability of Python on remote server

Install [sshuttle [image]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/sshuttle) from the Software Center or the Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install sshuttle
```

The basic command for running sshuttle with routing all traffic is:

```
sshuttle -r username@sshserver:port 0/0
```

Upon the execution of the command, a `sudo` password prompt will appear and subsequently the password to SSH account. No other details will appear except for a short message and return to shell upon failure. For more status messages, run `sshuttle` in verbose mode with the `-v` flag.

In this example all internet traffic except DNS is routed through the VPN. `-r` flag denotes the remote hostname and optional username and port that follows in the above example. `0/0` is short for `0.0.0.0/0` that represents the subnets to route over the VPN. The usage of `0/0` routes all the traffic except DNS requests to the remote server. DNS tunelling is possible with the usage of `-H` flag.

Please read the man page (`man sshuttle`) for the details of options and modes under which `sshuttle` can run. For information about the concept and more examples, refer to the [project page](https://github.com/apenwarr/sshuttle/).

Comment: [redsocks](http://darkk.net.ru/redsocks/) are also worth considering; same features, slightly different execution

Answer (score 18):

You cannot setup OpenVPN without root privileges because certain operations requires it.

- Prerequisites: you need to enable packet forwarding in your (iptables?) firewall
- Adding devices in operation: a special virtual device has to be added using `ifconfig`. Otherwise, no communication is possible between the server and client

Depending on your needs, other solutions are available. For browsing through your server, you may set up a SOCKS server.

### SOCKS proxy

Setting up a SOCKS proxy is not difficult: it's built-in in OpenSSH. To enable the SOCKS server, run the next command in [a terminal](https://askubuntu.com/q/38162/6969):

```
ssh user@host -D1234
```

Replace 1234 by your preferred port. In your browser, you can enter `localhost` as host and `1234` as port at SOCKS4/5 server.

Below is an example in the Firefox browser:

1. Go to *Edit* -> *Preferences*
2. Open the *Advanced* section
3. Go to the *Network* tab
4. Press *Settings*
5. Select *Manual proxy configuration*
6. Enter `localhost` as *SOCKS Host*
7. Enter `1234` as port (the same port as specified in the SSH command)
8. Press *OK* and *Close* to close the preferences dialogs.

[image: FIrefox setup example]

Comment: I want to route my internet through the system I want setup VPN on.

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot change the routing rules on the server without root privileges. One solution that provides at least a secure solution for browsing is by using a SOCKS proxy as described in the answer.

Comment: I succeeded in getting my internet routed over the SSH tunnel. Shall I edit your answer to specifically refer to that as I've edited the question? Or will you do it?

Comment: @Oxwivi: I'll re-order it and added an example for Firefox.

Answer (score -1):

If you only want to tunnel your systems TCP traffic i recommend to use a programm called tun2socks.
If you also want to tunnel UDP traffic you have to install udpgw on your server.

Here is an tutorial how to install and use this programms: http://board.nwrk.biz/viewtopic.php?id=3

Comment: Could you update your answer and explain the most important steps of your link here? This way this answer will still be useful even if the site will be gone.