# How can I set up password-less SSH login?

Tags: ssh, authentication

I want to be able to login to a remote via ssh without having to enter the password all the time.

- How do I set it up?
- Is a different command required to execute a password-less session?

Comment: Are you using openssh? (if so that's easy ;) )

Comment: @Rinzwind, Why would I bother getting the proprietary version when OpenSSH is already preinstalled?

Comment: I try to not make assuptions ;)

Comment: @Kevin, please clarify yourself. We're talking about ssh-ing without password, which is generally a *good practice*. Do you mean ssh-ing into a root shell? That's not covered by this question.

Comment: @Oxwivi: Sorry, this should have been a comment on Ravindra's answer, which is targeted at root login.

Comment: Just as a head's up. It is no longer necessary to enclose the custom port number and flag in quotes. ssh-copy-id -p 1234 userId@host

Answer (score 339, accepted):

#### Answer

Execute this command (if you already have an SSH key, you can skip this step):

```
ssh-keygen
```

[Then you'll need to copy the new key to your server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4830/easiest-way-to-copy-ssh-keys-to-another-machine/4833#4833):

```
ssh-copy-id user@host
## or if your server uses custom port no:
ssh-copy-id "user@host -p 1234"
```

After the key is copied, ssh into the machine as normal:

```
ssh user@host
```

You can now login without entering a password from the particular machine you executed the commands at.

#### Example

```
not-marco@rinzwind-desktop:~$ ssh-keygen
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/not-marco/.ssh/id_rsa):
Created directory '/home/not-marco/.ssh'.
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in /home/not-marco/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /home/not-marco/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
b1:25:04:21:1a:38:73:38:3c:e9:e4:5b:81:e9:ac:0f not-marco@rinzwind-desktop
The key's randomart image is:
+--[ RSA 2048]----+
|.o= . oo.        |
|*B.+ . .         |
|*=o .   o .      |
| = .     =       |
|. o     S        |
|E.               |
| o               |
|  .              |
|                 |
+-----------------+

not-marco@rinzwind-desktop:~$ ssh-copy-id not-marco@server
not-marco@server's password:
Now try logging into the machine, with "ssh 'not-marco@server'", and check in:

  ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

to make sure we haven't added extra keys that you weren't expecting.
```

#### Explanation

This assumes you already can successfully connect to your server via SSH.

You'll need to generate an SSH Keypair which will allow you to identify you as yourself without using a password. You can opt to protect keys with a passcode if you wish, but this can be left blank allowing totally password-less SSH access.

1. First create your SSH Keypair by running `ssh-keygen` this will create an `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` file. The `pub` file is what goes on the servers, the private key (`id_rsa`) is what stays with you and is how you identify yourself.
2. Next copy the public key to your server with `ssh-copy-id user@server` replacing user with your remote user and server with the machine DNS name or IP address. It'll prompt for your SSH password, enter it and if all completes successfully you'll be able to access the machine via `ssh user@server` without needing a password.

#### References

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys

Comment: @Oxwivi this answer is the more correct way to do it - but it seems longer. All you need to do is type `ssh-keygen` follow the on-screen instructions, then type `ssh-copy-id user@server` replacing user with your remote user and server with the remote machine

Comment: I had this error "Agent admitted failure to sign using the key." every time when trying to login after following this procedure. The solution was to run "> ssh-add" on the local machine and now I can log to the remote machine as expected.

Comment: It's worth to mention that if you need to use custom port for @server, you need to do this with: `ssh-copy-id "not-marco@127.0.0.1 -p 1234"`.

Comment: @Rinzwind: Does this mean that I can't ever authenticate from a unknown client/machine to my server if I disable passwd authentication & allow only key authentication. Is there any way to  allow login from unknown machine using the private key that was generated for known/configured client to communicate to server? I mean, is this private key portable & could be used to authenticate myself to server from other machines, in case of emergency needs ??

Comment: What if I want to ssh to many systems without passwords? This method is overwriting the existing keys and I am able to ssh to the last added system only without password.

Comment: Correct. But you generate -once- and copy those over to the other machine. See this for instance: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-multiple-ssh-key-based-authentication.html Oh and @RamanaReddy I would suggest it might be worth making a new topic asking about how to do this for multiple machine referring to this one ;)

Comment: But the server is still asking for the password,,,

Comment: How secure is the "totally passwordless" SSH access you mention?

Comment: Very. It is the best one among all the different methods.

Comment: Warning: By default `ssh-copy-id` will copy every key it can find -- which might open up access that you didn't intend.  To avoid this, use the `-i` option.

Comment: This is the right syntax to to specify the port:
`ssh-copy-id -p 1234 user@host`

Answer (score 44):

Type the following commands:

1. `ssh-keygen`

   Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key till you get the prompt
2. `ssh-copy-id -i root@ip_address`

   (It will once ask for the password of the host system)
3. `ssh root@ip_address`

Now you should be able to login without any password.

Comment: and to specify the port: `ssh-copy-id -p 1234 user@host`

Answer (score 28):

The way I usually do this is as follows:

`ssh-keygen -t rsa`

(When prompted for a password, leave it blank)

Then:
`cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh username@hostname 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'`

(This requires the folder .ssh to be in the home directory on the targeted hostname, with the authorized_keys file in it)

Of course, replace username with the desired username, and hostname with the desired hostname or IP address

After that, just SSH to that box just like you're used to.

Comment: What about the `touch` and `chmod` command in Rinzwind's answer?

Comment: You'll need to chmod the `.ssh/authorized_keys` file to 0600 or this will not work

Comment: This really helped because I couldn't get ssh-copy-id to work for root on my server. it has to be root in the situation where backuppc (or any other daemon) needs to ssh onto another machine.

Answer (score 20):

I normally use `sshpass` for that, install it with `sudo apt-get install sshpass` and use it like this

```
sshpass -p 'password' ssh your_username@your_server
```

Comment: Why not to use ssh keys?

Comment: Its not a "why not" situation, it still works perfect without adding keys, its just another method I would say.

Comment: Thanks for the information on sshpass, never heard of it before.

Comment: SSH keys are the "correct" answer to the question, but `sshpass` is a very useful hack in cases when you can't change the authentication method on the remote server!

Comment: This is very dangerous, you'll keep in bash_history or whatever the plain passwords for the hosts you're connecting to..

Comment: And if it still dangerous when you run the command as root ? If yes then anything is, I suppose.

Comment: @kappa put a space in front of command (eg `_sshpass` where `_` denotes space) to keep password out of bash history.

Answer (score 11):

> Disable Password Authentication
>
> Because a lot of people with SSH servers use weak passwords, many
>   online attackers will look for an SSH server, then start guessing
>   passwords at random. An attacker can try thousands of passwords in an
>   hour, and guess even the strongest password given enough time. The
>   recommended solution is to use SSH keys instead of passwords. To be as
>   hard to guess as a normal SSH key, a password would have to contain
>   634 random letters and numbers. If you'll always be able to log in to
>   your computer with an SSH key, you should disable password
>   authentication altogether.
>
> If you disable password authentication, it will only be possible to
>   connect from computers you have specifically approved. This massively
>   improves your security, but makes it impossible for you to connect to
>   your own computer from a friend's PC without pre-approving the PC, or
>   from your own laptop when you accidentally delete your key.
>
> It's recommended to disable password authentication unless you have a
>   specific reason not to.
>
> To disable password authentication, look for the following line in
>   your sshd_config file:
>
> ```
> #PasswordAuthentication yes
> ```
>
> replace it with a line that looks like this:
>
> ```
> PasswordAuthentication no
> ```
>
> Once you have saved the file and restarted your SSH server, you
>   shouldn't even be asked for a password when you log in.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Configuring#disable-password-authentication

Comment: This is the most basic correct answer but good for security! Also disable root login is another good one

Comment: Does `PasswordAuthentication no` affect all users? If not, how do I turn it off for normal users but leave it unchanged for root while I'm testing it? I don't really want to foobar it and lock myself out completely.

Comment: Keep an ssh session open so that you can change it back.  You want to disable passwords AND root.  Yes, you can fubar it.  Don't ;)

Comment: During ssh, I have an error `Permission denied (publickey).` with `PasswordAuthentication no`. What's should I do? Do I change `PasswordAuthentication no` on another host?

Answer (score 9):

*This solution is specifically for users using **Windows** to **ssh** into their remote machines including cloud images on **AWS Cloud** and **GCE Cloud***

#### Disclaimer

Recently used this solution to remote login new deployed vm images on GCE.

---

### Tools used:

1. `puttygen` [puttygen download](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/download.html)
2. `winscp` [winscp download](http://winscp.net/eng/download.php)

---

### Steps to perform:

1. Generate public/private key pair using puttygen.
2. Upload public key to your server in cloud or remote location.

### How to do it:

#### 1. Generate a key/pair or use existing private key

If you own a private key:

Open `puttygen`, press load button and select your private key (`*.pem`) file.

---

If you do not own a private key:

- Open `puttygen`,
- Select the desired key type SSH2 DSA (you may use RSA or DSA) within the **Parameters** section. It is important that you leave the passphrase field blank.
- Press <kbd>generate</kbd> and follow instructions to generate (public/private) key pair.

---

[image: Sample Key Generation pic]

(from source 1, link given below)

#### 2. Create a new 'authorized_keys' file (with `notepad`)

Copy your public key data from the "Public key for pasting into OpenSSH authorized_keys file" section of the PuTTY Key Generator, and paste the key data to the `authorized_keys` file.

---

Make sure there is only one line of text in this file.

---

#### 3. Upload key to the Linux server

- Open WinSCP,
- Select SFTP file protocol and login with your ssh credentials.
- On success, you see home directory structure at your remote machine.

---

Upload authorized_keys file to home directory at remote machine.

---

#### 4. Set proper permissions

Make `.ssh` directory (if not existing)

---

Copy `authorized_keys` file to `.ssh` directory.
(this will replace any existed `authorized_keys` file, take note of this).

If file existed, simply add contents of this file to the existing file.

---

Run commands to set permissions:

```
sudo chmod 700 .ssh && chmod 600 .ssh/authorized_keys
```

Now You will be able to `ssh` into remote machine without entering credentials every time.

### Further reading:

- [Generating and uploading SSH keys under Windows](https://opengear.zendesk.com/entries/23216142-Generating-and-uploading-SSH-keys-under-Windows)
- [OpsenSSH keys certificates authentication PEM PUB CRT](http://www.beginninglinux.com/home/server-administration/openssh-keys-certificates-authentication-pem-pub-crt)

Answer (score 5):

If you create a public/pricate keypair and log in using our newly created public key, you will not need to type your password. Depending on the configuration of your key-ring and/or ssh agent you might need to protect your key with a passphrase.

Here is one of many [short howto](http://www.ece.uci.edu/~chou/ssh-key.html)s for you. It is of crucial importance to the safety of this method, that the generated private key remains private! You should never share it with anyone or allow access of it in any capacity.

This command generates a reasonably strong key in `~/.ssh/`:

```
ssh-keygen -b 4096
```

In `~/.ssh/` you will find your public key as `id_rsa.pub`. Its contents should be appended to your servers `authorized_keys` file by transporting the via a transportable media (pen drive) or by shortly enabling password authentication on the server, then using `ssh-copy-id ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub username@server` and then disabling it again.

If you chose to secure your key with a passphrase (in the first step), you can use `ssh-agent` or the Ubuntu keyring to secure that pharse locally so you don't have to type it all the time.

Answer (score 3):

To make some additions:

- Mac by default doesn't have `ssh-copy-id`, you'll have to install it youself:

  ```
  curl https://raw.github.com/beautifulcode/ssh-copy-id-for-OSX/master/ssh-copy-id.sh -o /usr/local/bin/ssh-copy-id
  chmod +x /usr/local/bin/ssh-copy-id
  ```

find more here: https://github.com/beautifulcode/ssh-copy-id-for-OSX

- if you've made a port-forwarding, the command should be like this:

  ```
  ssh-copy-id "not-marco@127.0.0.1 -p 2222"
  ```

note that the quotes are necessary.

Answer (score 3):

### Remote login/copy without giving a password

The applications `ssh` and `scp` for remote login and remote copy, respectively, allow you to communicate with a remote host without giving a password. This requires that you follow an authentication procedure like the one described below. By client we mean the machine your are sitting on and by server we mean the machine you want to log onto without giving a password. The steps of the authentication procedure are:

1. Run ssh-keygen to generate private and public keys, unless this is already done on your machine. These are stored in files in `$HOME/.ssh`.
2. Append the contents of the public key file to the file `$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys` or `$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys2` on the server.

There are three different types of authentication protocols. You specify the type when running ssh-keygen:

1. **SSH** protocol version 1, **RSA1:** this is the default choice and results in files identity (private key, should take `chmod 0700` to ensure that this file is not readable for others) and **identity.pub** (public key).
2. **SSH** protocol version 1, **RSA**: this is obtained by running `ssh-keygen -t rsa` and results in files `id_rsa` (private key) and `id_rsa.pub` (public key)
3. **SSH** protocol version 1, **DSA**: this is obtained by running `ssh-keygen -t dsa` and results in files `id_dsa` (private key) and `id_dsa.pub` (public key)

When running ssh-keygen you can rely on default answers (implying that you do not give a passphrase). This makes the whole set-up simple, but also insecure.

You can specify the type of keys to be used by an option to **ssh**; `ssh -1` forces use of ***RSA1*** keys (protocol version 1), whereas `ssh -2` forces **ssh** to try ***RSA*** or ***DSA*** keys only (protocol version 2). In the examples below, we generate and install ***RSA1*** and ***DSA*** keys on the remote host such that you have more flexibility. You can make a config file in your `.ssh` directory with the line

```
Protocol 1,2
```

This makes **ssh** try an ***RSA1*** (protocol version 1) connection before ***RSA/DSA*** (protocol version 2).

### Using RSA1 keys

```
remote=user@remotehost   # fill in correct user and remotehost names
cd $HOME/.ssh
# create .ssh on remote host if it is non-existing:
ssh $remote 'if [ ! -d .ssh ]; then mkdir .ssh; fi' 
# copy RSA1 key: 
scp identity.pub ${remote}:.ssh
ssh $remote "cd .ssh; cat identity.pub >> authorized_keys"
```

### Using DSA keys

```
remote=user@remotehost   # fill in correct user and remotehost names
cd $HOME/.ssh
# create .ssh on remote host if it is non-existing:
ssh $remote 'if [ ! -d .ssh ]; then mkdir .ssh; fi' 
# copy DSA key: 
scp id_dsa.pub ${remote}:.ssh
ssh $remote "cd .ssh; cat id_dsa.pub >> authorized_keys2"
```

This is all you have to do if you did not use a passphrase when generating the keys. You can test the connection by running ssh $remote and see if you can log in without giving a password (you may need to use `-1` or `-2` as options to **ssh**). The procedure can, of course, be repeated for any machine you want to log onto.

If you did use a passphrase, you will have to run the program `ssh-agent` to start a special shell, followed by `ssh-add` to register your ***key/passphrase*** combination with `sshd`. See the man pages for these programs for more information.

### A script for automating password-free connections: `ssh-no-password.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh

# create ssh connections without giving a password

if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then
  echo Usage: $0 username@remotehost
  exit
fi
remote="$1"  # 1st command-line argument is the user@remotehost address
this=$HOST   # name of client host

# first check if we need to run ssh-keygen for generating
# $HOME/.ssh with public and private keys:
if [ ! -d $HOME/.ssh ]; then
  echo "just type RETURN for each question:" # no passphrase - unsecure!!
  # generate RSA1, RSA and DSA keys:
  echo; echo; echo
  ssh-keygen
  echo; echo; echo
  ssh-keygen -t rsa
  echo; echo; echo
  ssh-keygen -t dsa
else
  # we have $HOME/.ssh, but check that we have all types of
  # keys (RSA1, RSA, DSA):
  if [ ! -f $HOME/.ssh/identity ]; then
     # generate RSA1 keys:
     echo "just type RETURN for each question:" # no passphrase - unsecure!!
     ssh-keygen
  fi
  if [ ! -f $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa ]; then
     # generate RSA keys:
     echo "just type RETURN for each question:" # no passphrase - unsecure!!
     ssh-keygen -t rsa
  fi
  if [ ! -f $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa ]; then
     # generate DSA keys:
     echo "just type RETURN for each question:" # no passphrase - unsecure!!
     ssh-keygen -t dsa
  fi
fi


cd $HOME/.ssh

if [ ! -f config ]; then
  # make ssh try ssh -1 (RSA1 keys) first and then ssh -2 (DSA keys)
  echo "Protocol 1,2" > config
fi

# copy public keys (all three types) to the destination host:

echo; echo; echo
# create .ssh on remote host if it's not there:
ssh $remote 'if [ ! -d .ssh ]; then mkdir .ssh; fi' 
# copy RSA1 key: 
scp identity.pub ${remote}:.ssh/${this}_rsa1.pub
# copy RSA key:
#scp id_rsa.pub ${remote}:.ssh/${this}_rsa.pub
# copy DSA key:
scp id_dsa.pub ${remote}:.ssh/${this}_dsa.pub
# make authorized_keys(2) files on remote host:

echo; echo; echo
# this one copies all three keys:
#ssh $remote "cd .ssh; touch authorized_keys authorized_keys2; cat ${this}_rsa1.pub >> authorized_keys; cat ${this}_rsa.pub >> authorized_keys2; cat ${this}_dsa.pub >> authorized_keys2;"
# this one copies RSA1 and DSA keys:
ssh $remote "cd .ssh; touch authorized_keys authorized_keys2; cat ${this}_rsa1.pub >> authorized_keys; cat ${this}_dsa.pub >> authorized_keys2;"

echo; echo; echo
echo "try an ssh $remote"
```

<sub>copied from: http://folk.uio.no/hpl/scripting/doc/ssh-no-password.html</sub>

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to add an answer for those who may find they should enter the password even they have read all answers here because you have set IdentitiesOnly as yes. And the answer here can save you much time to manage multiple keys, being keys for git or server.

After I have generated the key and copied it to the server:

```
ssh-keygen  # change the file to /home/yourname/.ssh/something
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/something.pub lerner@192.168.20.160
```

I found it didn't work.

Then I went to check the `~/.ssh/config` file on the client, I saw this at the bottom:

```
Host *
IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Then I add this above:

```
Host somename
HostName 192.168.20.160
User lerner
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/something
```

I can just log in by entering `ssh somename`.

Then you can add multiple ssh keys using your favorite names, and you only need to add the settings like the above four lines to the config file.

Host is the name you'd like to enter when you connect the server later; the HostName is the server's ip; User is the user name you log in the server; and the identityfile is the file where you store the key you have generated.