# Is there a way to open 4 terminal windows every time I login?

Tags: gnome-terminal

I want to open four terminal windows into the first pane (upper left-hand side) when ubuntu boots.  I have two terminal profiles: default and Mail.  I want two of the windows Mail windows, and the other two to use the default profile.  It would also be nice if I could get the terminals to ssh to where I manually send them every time I boot up.

Is there a way to do this?  If so, what is it in English?  I am not a computer programmer or an expert user and i can't even tell whether I'm using unity, so please gear your answer accordingly.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You could add this to your startup applications. Press the Ubuntu button(top-left), type and click Startup Applications, there, click on Add and type whatever you want in the title and put this is in the command section:

`gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=default && gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=default && gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=Mail && gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=Mail`

[image: startup]

As for your automatic SSH logging in needs please take a look at this question here - [Can I create a SSH script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61963/can-i-create-an-ssh-login-script/61969#61969) and [How can I setup password-less SSH](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46930/how-can-i-set-up-password-less-ssh-login)

Answer (score 0):

**NEEDS EDITING (LATER)**

> Is there a way to do this? If so, what is it in English? I am not a
>   computer programmer or an expert user and i can't even tell whether
>   I'm using unity, so please gear your answer accordingly

The best way to make program start at login, regardless of desktop environment (unity,gnome,whatever), is to place a file like `program-name.desktop` into a folder `.config/autostart/` (this folder is in your home folder, hidden because of the initial dot.) . Whatever is in that file, will run when you login.

Bellow is the version of a script I wrote for [another question](https://askubuntu.com/a/586977/295286), but adapted for this specific one. You would need to open text editor ( named gedit ), and copy the following:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=four-terminals
Comment=A script to open 4 terminal windows.
Exec=/home/yourusername/bin/four-terminals.sh
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Application;
```

Notice the line `Exec=`, where `yourusername` should be substituted with your actual user name. This is the *path to the file* that will actually do the work. You you will need to make a new folder in your home folder called `bin` and then create a file called `four-terminals.sh` in there. Copy the script bellow into that file. Now , open terminal  and type `sudo chmod +x /home/yourusername/four-terminals.sh`

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# Author: Serg Kolo
# Date: 2/18/2015
# Description: A simple script to create two windows on right side
# of the screen with specific size. 

sleep 1
# This part opens 4 windows with specific profiles and titles 
gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=Mail -t MAIL-ONE 
gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=Mail -t MAIL-TWO
gnome-terminal -t DEFAULT-ONE
gnome-terminal -t DEFAULT-TWO
if [  $? == 0  ]
then
        wmctrl -r MAIL-ONE -e 0,1300,300,250,250
        sleep 0.5
        wmctrl -r MAIL-TWO -e 0,1300,0,250,250
        sleep 0.5
        wmctrl -r DEFAULT-ONE -e 0,1000,300,250,250
        sleep 0.5
        wmctrl -r DEFAULT-TWO -e 0,1000,0,250,250
fi
```

Comment: Perhaps it's simply not clear yet: `if command; then ...` is the same as `command; if [ $? = 0 ]; then ...`.

Comment: I know , but I just find it less confusing for me. Just a personal quirk

Comment: Are you sure? You wouldn't have made that mistake with `sleep` in the previous script. Also, your answers should help others as well, so please stick to simpler code if you can.

Comment: Ok , I will try. Thank you for always helping users improve , muru ! You're awesome !