# nautilus --geometry=?

Tags: nautilus

Trying to open nautilus in a fixed position from a script, but it looks like there is a bug with the "--geometry" option.  So my question, does anyone know of another way to force the nautilus window position to a specific size and placement?

My script is going to be tied in with a bit of python to create an old school midnight commander type feature.  This is a project of mine, so I'd like to build my own rather than use something already built.

Thanks for the help in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of specifying `--geometry` parameter, try specifying it with `-g` parameter. If it still doesn't work, I would consider this a bug.

An alternative to using the nautilus' native `--geometry` parameter, would be to use `wmctrl` , which can be used to control any other type of graphical window. This app doesn't come by default, so  you have to download it with `sudo apt-get install wmctrl`.

The command to position and scale the window would be `wmctrl -r WINDOW_TITLE -e 0,XOFFSET,YOFFSET,WIDTH,HEIGHT`. I've used this method on another question, to position two terminal windows with specific size and location (refer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/586977/295286))

Another , slightly better way , is to find out window id (a hex number) with `xprop` or `wmctrl` itself, and use that with `-i -r` parameters. Title of the Nautilus window changes as file folder changes, so this would be slightly more reliable.

Let me know if you'd like me to elaborate more on this.

Comment: Thanks for the information on this.  I have been looking for something similar and have finally figured out a way to script the opening and placement of two nautilus windows using a bash script.  I was able to pull the window ids and make the placements needed.

As a side note, this also works on Arch.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Serge's answer this works for me:

```
nautilus && sleep .1 && wmctrl -Fr "Home" -e '0,3633,1605,930,514'
```

- `sleep .1` (sleep for 1/10th second for `nautilus` startup time) is how fast my system works. You might try `sleep 1` or `sleep 2` and work your way down.
- `Home` is the name of my Nautilus window. If your nautilus opens to a different location the title bar window name will be different. In that case use it instead.
- `3633,1605` is 3633 pixels to left and 1605 pixels down on my system. You can start at `300,200` for your system and increase appropriately.
- `930,514` is 930 pixels wide and 514 pixels high for the nautilus window on my system. Yours might be 400x300 or something in between. Experiment to your preferences.

You need `wmctrl` to make this work:

```
sudo apt install wmctrl
```