# SSH connecting with one command line

Tags: ssh

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I set up password-less SSH login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46930/how-can-i-set-up-password-less-ssh-login)

I'm trying to connect to the ssh with the following command:

```
ssh user:pass@host
```

bit still it's asking the password, how can I login without asking the password again?

Comment: Search for 'ssh no password' on askubuntu.com :)
http://askubuntu.com/questions/46930/how-can-i-set-up-password-less-ssh-login