# Can you set passwords in .ssh/config to allow automatic login?

Tags: command-line, bash, ssh, remote-access

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 and `ssh` for connecting to many servers daily, so I put their parameters in the `.ssh/config` file like this:

```
Host Home
User netmoon
Port 22
HostName test.com
```

Is there a way to put passwords for each connection in this file, so that, when the server asks for the password, the terminal enters its password and sends it to the server?

I need this because sometimes I'm away from the PC and when I get back, type a password, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> the terminal says `CONNECTION CLOSED`.

P.S. I don't want to use a public/private key pair.

Comment: I'm in the same situation and I cannot upload my public key because I have ssh access only for svn. That is if I try 
ssh svnhost

I get "( success ( 2 2 ( ) ( edit-pipeline svndiff1 absent-entries commit-revprops depth log-revprops partial-replay ) ) )" svnserve response and not the shell

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/83991/26493 and http://andre.frimberger.de/index.php/linux/reading-ssh-password-from-stdin-the-openssh-5-6p1-compatible-way/ for a way by utilizing `SSH_ASKPASS`.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Trading off security for convenience never ends well...

Could you use `ssh-copy-id` from the `openssh-client` package?

From `man ssh-copy-id`:

> ssh-copy-id is a script that uses ssh to log into a remote 
>   machine and append the indicated identity file to that 
>   machine's ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file.

Comment: This doesn't work if the remote admin insists on disabling public key authorization...

Comment: Yes, but being realistic on systems under your entire direct supervision and control is not making a compromise. Say, for example, on a vagrant virtual machine with no outside connections used solely for development purposes on a single seat.

Comment: Insisting on draconian security without cause also never ends well.

Comment: Sometimes it ends well.

Comment: IMHO, the insistence of passwords for authentication is more risk than not. I oftentimes set often used passwords for ssh as environment variables as I am loath to remember  a set of arbitrary strings. By demanding users enter them is simply asking them to be poorly stored.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I read "I don't want to use public/private key pair.", but can't figure out where.... So: "I don't want to use public/private key pair." => Ok, why don't you use a public/private key pair ?

Comment: I'm genuinely curious, how is saving a password in you ssh_config, different from having a private key stored on your system? Does using a password lead to weaker encryption between the client and server?

Comment: this is not a security related question. the question asked concerns automation, not security.

Comment: @AndreHelberg, if the private key is *unencrypted*, then it's equally insecure. However, if your SSH key requires a passphrase to unlock, meaning it is stored encrypted on disk, then this is not the case. Using `UseKeychain yes` in your SSH config, in conjunction with a native keychain manager (e.g. macOS Keychain Access, GNOME keyring/libsecret) means that, if you're logged in to your local machine, the encrypted key will be automatically decrypted without prompting you for the key's passphrase, but the key still remains encrypted on disk.

Answer (score 27):

If you don't really want to use a public/private key pair, you can write an `expect` script to enter the password for you automatically depending on the destination address.

Edit: What I mean is that you can have a script that, on one hand, uses `expect` to enter the password for you and, on the other hand, reads the password for a given user and host from a configuration file. For example, the following python script will work for the sunny day scenario:

```
#!/usr/bin/python                                                                                                                        
import argparse
from ConfigParser import ConfigParser
import pexpect

def main(args):
    url = args.url
    user, host = url.split('@', 1)

    cfg_file = 'ssh.cfg'
    cfg = ConfigParser()
    cfg.read(cfg_file)
    passwd = cfg.get(user, host)

    child = pexpect.spawn('ssh {0}'.format(url))
    child.expect('password:')
    child.sendline(passwd)
    child.interact()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Run ssh through pexpect')
    parser.add_argument('url')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    main(args)
```

and the configuration file format would be as follows:

```
[user_1]
host1 = passwd_1
host2 = passwd_2

[user_2]
host1 = passwd_1
host2 = passwd_2
```

Note: As explained, the python script would need to be much more complex to handle all the possible errors and question messages from ssh and all the possible URLs (in the example it's assumed that it will be something like `user@host`, but the user part isn't used most of the times), but the basic idea would still be the same. Regarding the configuration file, you may use a different configuration file or use `.ssh/config` and write your own code to parse that file and get the password for a given user and host.

Comment: can you explain further?

Comment: @Netmoon I added a small example to my answer to my it clearer.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of how to put the password in the .ssh/config file

Comment: Indeed, it does not answer that question. But it solves the problem: avoid having to type passwords manually and store them in a file. Which is pretty what OP requires.

Answer (score 24):

How about ProxyCommand:

```
Host Home-raw
    HostName test.com
Host Home
   User netmoon
   Port 22
   ProxyCommand sshpass -pmypass ssh netmoon@%h-raw nc localhost %p
```

You can use `ssh -W` instead of `nc` as well:

```
ProxyCommand sshpass -pmypass ssh netmoon@%h-raw -W localhost:%p
```

Comment: It will not work as expected with `-W` option. Do you have any workaround?

Comment: It still asks me for the password with this proxy command...

Comment: I also find it still asks for a password.  All this seems to do is move the problem from `test.com` requiring a password to `Home` requiring a password.   What's the point? What's the trick to get it to work?

Answer (score 21):

There also is `sshpass` program for that.
How to use:
`sshpass -p MyPa55word ssh me@myservor.com`

Comment: Unless you preface your command with a space, (`sshpass` instead of `sshpass`), you have just stored your password ("MyPa55word") in your shell's history file.

Comment: @waltinator good point

Comment: Well the question asker was fine with it being in `.ssh/config`, why not in shell history too?

Comment: It's not officially on Homebrew but you can install from a third-party repo with `brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kadwanev/bigboybrew/master/Library/Formula/sshpass.rb`. More: https://gist.github.com/arunoda/7790979

Comment: `read -s password; sshpass -p "$password" ssh me@myservor.com`. This will prevent password from showing in history

Comment: A well-timed (or repeated) `ps -lf -C sshpass` will catch the password, unless `sshpass` clears its environment.

Comment: ` export SSHPASS='YourPass'; sshpass -e ssh me@server`

Answer (score 16):

No. This is not possible I'm afraid.

The only real alternative is to use private keys but you've said you don't want to (why not?).

Comment: because i don't have permission to put another key on server.

Comment: @Netmoon: If you can log in, you can add a key, right? You only need write access to your home directory, unless the sysadmin set things up strangely.

Comment: @ScottSeverance I think that is the situation this question refers to.  Not having the ability to add a key.  Yes it is strange, but it often happens.

Comment: I've had the very common experience of shared hosting environments where public key access is disabled, so even though you can add keys, they are not used.  it goes against reason yes, but that's the way many hosting providers set up their servers

Comment: There are answers that show it is possible

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost It's not ok to solicit downvotes on a post. If there is something wrong with this answer then post that in a polite manner.

Comment: This is the only valid answer to the OP's question: "can I put a password in the config file?"  While all the other answers a helpful, they do not *directly* answer the OP's question.

Answer (score 8):

You can create a simple ssh script replacement in /usr/local/bin:

```
#!/bin/bash

host=$1
password=`awk "/#Password/ && inhost { print \\\$2 } /Host/ { inhost=0 } /Host $host/ { inhost=1 }" ~/.ssh/config`

if [[ -z "$password" ]]; then
  /usr/bin/ssh $*
else
  sshpass -p $password /usr/bin/ssh $*
fi
```

And then in your ~/.ssh/config file you can use

```
Host foohost
    User baruser
    #Password foobarpassword
```

Answer (score 4):

Answering the question you asked, no it's not possible to configure a default password in an ssh config file.

But if indeed, as you say, it's *"because sometimes I stand away from the PC and when I go back, type a password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> the terminal says `CONNECTION CLOSED`"*, then why not prevent closing the session instead? SSH can keep connections alive for you.

```
Host Home
  User netmoon
  Port 22
  HostName test.com
  ServerAliveInterval 300
  ServerAliveCountMax 2
```

Answer (score 3):

I use an application from VanDyke Software called **SecureCRT**.

http://www.vandyke.com/products/securecrt/

It is not free, but very reasonably priced.  I have used it for years (running on Windows, or using Wine) for remote access, terminal emulation, and (dispersed) network management.  They finally released a native Linux version of this at the beginning of 2011.

It has support for complex login settings (or scripts), stored passwords (or certificates), tabbed multiple sessions, etc.

At startup you can choose which remote target (and protocol) from a structured list (tree view) of stored remote (or local) machines, or just create a connection (which is then stored).

I have found it particularly useful for remote sites with advanced authentication, non-standard ports, or firewall-access negotiation.

If you are doing remote access a lot (part of your main role), then this application will justify its expense in the first month of use.

Comment: sorry, i don't understand. can you explain ?

Comment: reworded for you ..

Comment: Since posting of the above response there has been several iterations of SecureCRT, including the latest one VanDyke just released in early December 2013. Each iteration has been improving the program making it even more versatile. It also has a rich API that allows the program to be controlled/interfaced with Python/VB scripts. SecureCRT has been part of my core toolkit for a good decade, and I highly recommend it.

Comment: ***Agreed.** I continue to beta-test each new release, and was heavily involved in early testing for porting to **Ubuntu**.*

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by @[Arek Burdach's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/829837) and others' wrapper, I've wrote a wrapper that should be more robust which facilitated ssh own command parsing.

UPDATE 2021-04-26: Fixed wrapper when a host only matches the prefix (e.g. Host is none)

Here's how it work:

- We first dry-run the ssh with -v and a non-existent ProxyCommand, so it wouldn't make any network connection and exit at once.
- Then we extract the line like `debug1: /home/misty/.ssh/config line 42: Applying options for XXXXXX`. But the ssh output the errlog with \r, so we replaced them before passing into grep.

According to my test, ssh will only recognize the first -o ProxyCommand=XXX in commandline, even if there's second ProxyCommand option in the cmdline, or there's ProxyCommand in ~/.ssh/config, so our method will be very very stable ;)

For ssh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
ORISSH=/usr/bin/ssh
ssh_dryrun=$($ORISSH -v -o "ProxyCommand=FAKE_PROXY_STUB %h %p" "$@" 2>&1 | sed -e 's/\r/\n/g')
host=$( grep -oP 'Applying options for \K(.*?)$' <<< $ssh_dryrun | head -n 1 )

if [[ $host == "*" ]]; then
  password=''
else
  password=`awk "/#Password/ && inhost { print \\\$2 } /^Host/ { inhost=0 } /Host $host$/ { inhost=1 }" ~/.ssh/config`
fi

if [[ -z "$password" ]]; then
  $ORISSH "$@"
else
  sshpass -p $password $ORISSH "$@"
fi
```

For scp:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
ORISCP=/usr/bin/scp
scp_dryrun=$($ORISCP -v -o "ProxyCommand=proxyhost %h %p" "$@" 2>&1 | sed -e 's/\r/\n/g')
host=$( grep -oP 'Applying options for \K(.*?)$' <<< $scp_dryrun | head -n 1 )

if [[ $host == "*" ]]; then
  password=""
else
  password=`awk "/#Password/ && inhost { print \\\$2 } /^Host/ { inhost=0 } /Host $host$/ { inhost=1 }" ~/.ssh/config`
fi

if [[ -z "$password" ]]; then
  $ORISCP "$@"
else
  sshpass -p $password $ORISCP "$@"
fi
```

Comment: @Nmath Oh thanks a lot for your helpful instruction! I'll pay attention to this issue in the future :)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, Arek for the inspiration...

Rather than running another shell process, this is just a function running in the current bash shell. It runs a single `awk` command to parse the config file and figure out if it should take the password from a shell variable or from the password written cleartext into the ssh config file (with `awk` in an `eval` instead of `declare` due to issues I hit using `declare`).

I tried so many ways of using `sshpass` directly in an `ssh` config file using ProxyCommand, but nothing seemed to work as expected, except when I could log in to a box via RSA and then I needed to send a password to open my encrypted directory. However, my function below seems to work for me in all cases, even for Cygwin.

```bash
# In your .bash_profile
function ssh(){
    host=$1;
    unset PASSWORD
    unset PASSVAR
    eval $(awk "/ *#[Pp]assvar / && inhost { printf \"PASSVAR=%s\",\$2; exit 1 } / *#[Pp]assword / && inhost { printf \"PASSWORD=%s\",\$2; } /^#?[Hh][oO][sS][tT] / && inhost { inhost=0; exit 1 } /^[Hh][oO][sS][tT] $host\$/ { inhost=1 }" ~/.ssh/config)
    if [[ -z "$PASSWORD" ]] && [[ -z "$PASSVAR" ]]; then
        /usr/bin/ssh -q $* 2>/dev/null
    else
       if [[ -n "$PASSVAR" ]]; then
          PASSWORD=$(TMP=${!PASSVAR-*};echo ${TMP##*-})
       fi
       /usr/local/bin/sshpass -p"$PASSWORD" /usr/bin/ssh -q $* 2>/dev/null
    fi
}
# and setup your passwords (perhaps in .bashrc instead...)
MYPASS_ENVVAR=SomePassword
MYPASSWD_FROM_FILE=$(</home/me/.passwd_in_file)
```

Then a `~/.ssh/config` section looks like this:

```
Host MyHostname
 Port 22
 Hostname 2.1.2.2
 User merrydan
 #Passvar MYPASS_ENVVAR
 #Password Some!Password
```

If a  `#Passvar`  exists in the config section this overrides the  `#Password`.
`$MYPASS_ENVVAR` is the environment variable holding your password.

Enjoy!

And something to handle most scp scenarios (not fully fleshed but at least a start...)

```bash
function scp(){
    host=$(echo $* | perl -pe 's/^.*?([A-Za-z-1-9-]+):.*?$/\1/;');
    unset PASSWORD
    unset PASSVAR

    eval $(awk "/^#[Pp]assvar / && inhost { printf \"PASSVAR=%s\",\$2; exit 1; } /^ *#[Pp]assword / && inhost { printf \"PASSWORD=%s\",\$2; } /^#?[Hh][oO][sS][tT] / && inhost { inhost=0; exit 1; } /^[Hh][oO][sS][tT] $host\$/ { inhost=1 }" ~/.ssh/config.d/*)
    if [[ -z "$PASSWORD" ]] && [[ -z "$PASSVAR" ]]; then
        #echo /usr/bin/scp -3 $*
        /usr/bin/scp -3 $* || true
        #echo "SSH Exit Code $?"
    else
       if [[ -n "$PASSVAR" ]]; then
          #PASSWORD=`echo ${!PASSVAR}`
          PASSWORD=$(TMP=${!PASSVAR-*};echo ${TMP##*-})
       fi
       #echo /usr/local/bin/sshpass -p"$PASSWORD" /usr/bin/scp -3 $*
       /usr/bin/sshpass -p"$PASSWORD" /usr/bin/scp -3 $* || true
       #echo "SSHPass Exit Code $?"
    fi
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer of @BrunoPereira to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46930/how-can-i-set-up-password-less-ssh-login) shows an alternative method to connect without explicitly entering a password and avoiding ssh keys.

You could create a script, an alias or a function in your `~/.bashrc` to quickly execute that command.

Obviously, there are security considerations you should take into account with this approach.

Comment: It's great that you link to a solution - however, it's also good practice to go ahead and post the solution here.  That way, if the link is ever removed (as happens on stack exchange occasionally) there is still a usable answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my elaborate variation on @ArekBurdach's answer. It offers the following extensions:

- the *host* can be anywhere in the `ssh` command-line; i.e. it also supports the `ssh <args> <host> <commands>` syntax
- does not hard-code the path to `ssh`
- more robust parsing of `ssh_config`
- Bonus: wrapper for `scp`, too

#### `ssh-wrapper`

```
#!/bin/bash

password=$(awk '
BEGIN {
    # Collect the SSH arguments as keys of a dictionary, so that we can easily
    # check for inclusion.
    for (i = 2; i < ARGC; i++) {
        sshArgs[ARGV[i]] = 1
    }

    # Only process the first argument; all others are the command-line arguments
    # given to ssh.
    ARGC = 2
}
$1 == "Password" && inhost { print $2 }
/^\s*Host\s/ {
    if ($2 in sshArgs)
        inhost=1
    else
        inhost=0
}
' ~/.ssh/config "$@")


if [ "$password" ]; then
    sshpass -p "$password" ssh "$@"
else
    exec ssh "$@"
fi
```

#### `scp-wrapper`

```
#!/bin/bash

password=$(awk '
BEGIN {
    # Collect the SCP arguments as keys of a dictionary, so that we can easily
    # check for inclusion.
    for (i = 2; i < ARGC; i++) {
        colonIdx = index(ARGV[i], ":")
        if (colonIdx > 0) {
            scpArgs[substr(ARGV[i], 1, colonIdx - 1)] = 1
        }
    }

    # Only process the first argument; all others are the command-line arguments
    # given to scp.
    ARGC = 2
}
$1 == "Password" && inhost { print $2 }
/^\s*Host\s/ {
    if ($2 in scpArgs)
        inhost=1
    else
        inhost=0
}
' ~/.ssh/config "$@")


if [ "$password" ]; then
    sshpass -p "$password" scp "$@"
else
    exec scp "$@"
fi
```

#### Installation

Define aliases in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias ssh=ssh-wrapper
alias scp=scp-wrapper
```

#### Configuration

With the `IgnoreUnknown` directive, `ssh` does not complain about a newly introduced `Password` directive, so (in contrast to @ArekBurdach's answer), we can make this appear as a "real" configuration. If you don't like this, it's trivial to change the script back to the commented-out one.

```
# Allow specifying passwords for Host entries, to be parsed by ssh-wrapper.
IgnoreUnknown Password

Host foohost
    User baruser
    Password foobarpassword
```

Comment: I like your solution more, but it's not working for me. $password is always empty.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have direct access to key-pair, you could encrypt password on your local machine.

The way to do it is [encrypt your password using key](https://superuser.com/questions/576506/how-to-use-ssh-rsa-public-key-to-encrypt-a-text) in addition to @Eric Woodruff 's ProxyCommand.

A way to combine is using pipe:

```
openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey /path/to/decrypt_key -in /path/to/encrypted_password  | sshpass ssh real-destination -tt
```

where

```
Host real-destination
    Hostname test.com
    User netmoon
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a slight variant of a way described in the blog on how to use `sshpass`
which can be found [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/noninteractive-shell-script-ssh-password-provider/). Given that you have a gpg encrypted password (how ot do this is described in the blog) file you could do something like this:

```
 sshpass -p $(echo $(gpg -d -q .sshpasswd.gpg)) ssh your_desination.xyz
```

and simply save that command as an alias in your  `.bashrc` .

If you want to tunnel through that connection you could do something like

```
 Host actual_dest
      Hostname actual.dest.xyz
      User username
      ProxyCommand sshpass -p $(echo $(gpg -d -q ~/.sshpasswd.gpg)) \ 
                   ssh your_destination.xyz nc %h %p
```

Answer (score 0):

Because I cannot find documentation on how to implement key-based authentication for a Windows ssh server I am forced to use password authentication to access files and directories hosted by Windows.

Below are working Python3 versions of the ssh and scp wrapper programs in the answer by @IngoKarkat. This assumes that you store the password in `~/.ssh/config` just as he suggests:

```
# Allow specifying passwords for Host entries, to be parsed by ssh-wrapper and scp-wrapper.
IgnoreUnknown Password

Host foohost
    User baruser
    Password foobarpassword
```

Before running these programs first install the `sshconf` Python library:

```bsh
$ pip3 install sshconf
```

These programs first attempt to find a password, and if none is available they fall back to key-based authentication.

### Enhanced `ssh`

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from __future__ import print_function
import shutil, subprocess, sys
from sshconf import read_ssh_config
from os.path import expanduser

c: str = read_ssh_config(expanduser("~/.ssh/config"))

if len(sys.argv) == 1:
  print(f"Usage: {sys.argv[0]} host [command]")
  sys.exit(1)

if shutil.which("sshpass") == None:
  print("Please install sshpass and retry.")
  sys.exit(2)

host: str = sys.argv[1]
try:
  password: str = c.host(host)["password"]
  command = [ "sshpass", f"-p{password}", "ssh", host ] + sys.argv[2:]
except KeyError:
  command = [ "ssh", host ] + sys.argv[2:]

subprocess.run(command)
```

### Enhanced `scp`

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# Python3 version of https://askubuntu.com/a/878335/58760
#
# See https://github.com/sorend/sshconf
#
# pip3 install sshconf

from __future__ import print_function
import shutil, subprocess, sys
from sshconf import read_ssh_config
from os.path import expanduser

c: str = read_ssh_config(expanduser("~/.ssh/config"))

if len(sys.argv) < 3:
  print(f"""Usage: 
  {sys.argv[0]} /dir1 host2:/dir2
  {sys.argv[0]} host1:/dir1 /dir2""")
  sys.exit(1)

if shutil.which("sshpass") == None:
  print("Please install sshpass and retry.")
  sys.exit(2)

try:
  host = sys.argv[1].rsplit(":", 1)[0]
  password: str = c.host(host)["password"]
  command = [ "sshpass", f"-p{password}" ] 
except KeyError:
  try:
    host = sys.argv[2].rsplit(":", 1)[0]
    password: str = c.host(host)["password"]
    command = [ "sshpass", f"-p{password}" ] 
  except KeyError:
    command = [ ]

command = command + [ "scp" ] + sys.argv[1:]

subprocess.run(command)
```

### Saving and Running

I stored the programs in the `~/.local/bin/` directory, which is the recommended Ubuntu directory for user scripts.

To use the programs, first make them executable. Assuming you stored them in `~/.local/bin/sshPass` and `~/.local/bin/scpPass`, type the following to make them executable:

```bsh
$ chmod a+x ~/.local/bin/sshPass
$ chmod a+x ~/.local/bin/scpPass
```

You can run them like this:

```bsh
$ ~/.local/bin/sshPass hostName ls
$ ~/.local/bin/scpPass hostName:fromFile toFile
$ ~/.local/bin/scpPass fromFile hostName:toFile
```

You could also add this to `~/.bash_aliases`, for *nix distros that support that, or your startup bash script:

```
alias ssh=~/.local/bin/sshPass
alias scp=~/.local/bin/scpPass
```