# How to setup login your SSH server with Public/Private key authentification?

Tags: ssh, login

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I set up password-less SSH login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46930/how-can-i-set-up-password-less-ssh-login)

I am having a debian based linode server. All the time if need to login to remote server i do

```
   ssh user@ip
```

and then I enter my password to login on remote server. How an I do the same thing using public and private key. Cause I don't want to give password to other ppls.

Comment: This did not work for you: http://askubuntu.com/questions/46930/how-can-i-set-up-password-less-ssh-login/46935#46935 ?

Answer (score 0):

use ssh-keygen command to generate private and public key.
Add your public key ( id_rsa.pub) in server's authorized_keys file ( located inside .ssh or create if doesn't exist ).

to allow others to login on your computer tell them to run ssh-keygen command on their computer, take their *.pub file and append inside ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file.

Comment: It was working for me but. Its not working for me.