# How can I use a passcode generator for authentication for remote logins?

Tags: ssh, security, authentication, pam

I would like to strengthen the authentication of my SSH logins by adding another factor: a passcode generator device, or a passcode generation application on my mobile phone. The only obvious options in the default setup are a fixed password and key pair. How can I do this?

(If I use a password plus a passcode generator, this provides [two-factor authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-factor_authentication) (2FA): the password is “what I know”, and the passcode is “what I have”.)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

One way to do this is with a tool provided by Google called [Google Authenticator](http://code.google.com/p/google-authenticator/).

1. Install [libpam-google-authenticator](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/libpam-google-authenticator) [image: Install libpam-google-authenticator]

   - or just `sudo apt-get install libpam-google-authenticator`
2. Edit `/etc/pam.d/sshd` to include the module:

   - `sudoedit /etc/pam.d/sshd`
   - and then include this line at the **top of the file** and save:

     ```
     auth required pam_google_authenticator.so
     ```
3. Edit your SSH config file to turn on the challenge:

   - `sudoedit /etc/ssh/sshd_config` and then change the response authentication from:

     ```
     ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
     ```

     to

     ```
     ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
     ```

     and then save the file.
4. `sudo restart ssh` to restart SSH
5. Run `google-authenticator`

   - This will give you your secret key, verification code, and emergency scratch codes. It will also ask you some rate limiting questions.

#### Mobile Applications:

You'll need one of these to receive the authentication code on another device.

- [Android App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.authenticator2)
- [iPhone App](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/google-authenticator/id388497605?mt=8)

#### Related and Useful:

- Most of this answer is derived from [this blogpost](http://blog.theroux.ca/security/ubuntu-2-step-authentication-with-google-authenticator/) by Jean-Francois Theroux but updated.
- [Google Authenticator Wiki](http://code.google.com/p/google-authenticator/w/list)
- http://guides.webbynode.com/articles/security/ubuntu-google-authenticator.html
- http://www.mnxsolutions.com/security/two-factor-ssh-with-google-authenticator.html
- It is my understanding that if you're using passwordless logins via SSH keys that you can only do one or the other, see this question: [How can I set up password-less SSH login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46930/how-can-i-set-up-password-less-ssh-login)
- And if you're using Puppet, there's a puppet module here: https://github.com/camptocamp/puppet-googleauthenticator
- See Maarten's answer and link to github issue on why you need to add the .so line at the top of your pam config: https://askubuntu.com/a/668398

Note that combining a password with single-use passcodes is two-factor authentication: it combines “what you know” (a password) with “what you have” (the passcode generator device). On the other hand, if you combine single-use passcodes with an SSH key pair, it's all about “what you have”. When two authentication factors are of the same type, you do not have two-factor authentication; this is sometimes called “one-and-a-half-factor authentication”.

Comment: In Ubuntu 22.04 the `ChallengeResponseAuthentication` is replaced by `KbdInteractiveAuthentication` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

Answer (score 12):

Google Authenticator is fine for your personal servers but you might find that it doesn't tie in well with your existing identity infrastructure.  If you want to explore other options think about using RADIUS as an authentication protocol and the pam-radius plugin.  All the enterprise-oriented two-factor authentication systems support radius.  We have written a doc on how to add [WiKID two-factor authentication via pam-radius to Ubuntu](http://www.wikidsystems.com/support/wikid-support-center/how-to/how-to-configure-pam-radius-in-ubuntu).

Using radius allows you to tie in other systems besides SSH to the same authentication server. You can also route auth requests through freeradius to LDAP and then to your 2FA server to separate authorization from authentication. You can do the same with AD btw.

Answer (score 1):

I urge everybody to put the following line at the **top and not at the bottom** of `/etc/pam.d/sshd` as described above previously (now corrected):

```
auth required pam_google_authenticator.so
```

Otherwise your system will remain **open to brute force attacks** on your password, comprimising the first part of the two-factor authentication: your password.

You will be asked first for your verification code, and then your password (regardless if the code was correct). If either one is wrong you need to enter both again. You can configure it the other way around but that's a bit more difficult change to describe in the current default ubuntu (15.04) sshd configuration.

For details why it's needed, check this issue:

https://github.com/google/google-authenticator/issues/514