# custom SSH and Login authentication

Tags: server, ssh, password, login-screen

I am trying to figure out how to change the authorization process for ssh and normal logins. I have used public and private keys before but now I want to try using something else. I already have the program written now, I just need help implementing it. I was doing some research on GRUB and still was not able to find the process.

I'm going to implement a dynamic password system. I don't like static passwords or keys.

Comment: It's unclear what you actually want to do and need help with - maybe elaborate?

Comment: I updated it. Im just trying to switch out the traditional authentication for something custom.

Comment: the files that manage the authentication configuration are, **on client:** /etc/ssh/ssh_config, **on server:** /etc/ssh/sshd_config - i guess you will have to configure both files, the authentication "type" is showed on the sshd_config.

Comment: Thank you, I looked into both files and I think your on to something. I am not sure what calls this file. If I can figure that part out and replace it with my own code, I should be good to go.

Comment: Password based login in normal login is handled by PAM. ssh also calls pam when password authentication is required.

Comment: Also see https://askubuntu.com/questions/159727/how-can-i-use-a-passcode-generator-for-authentication-for-remote-logins

Comment: This is a lot closer to what I wanted. It will take some time to sort everything. I will possibly make a free alternative tool for everyone. It will not be Jalyn's Algorithm but powerful and interesting.