# How can I make ssh-copy-id use a port other than 22?

Tags: bash, ssh

How can I make ssh-copy-id use a port other than 22?

I tried it with -p but I get:

```
ssh-copy-id -p XXX XXXX@XX.XX.XX.XX
Bad port 'umask 077; test -d ~/.ssh || mkdir ~/.ssh ; cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys'
```

I know that the port is good because I'm connected to the server on that port.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the port to use in `~/.ssh/config` like the following:

```
Host secret-host.example.com
Port 2222
```

Answer (score 12):

I use this command, note the quotes:

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub "user@host -p 6842"
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
ssh-copy-id "user@host -p 8888"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub ‘-p 221 username@host’
```

From: [Is it possible to run ssh-copy-id on port other than 22?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29401/is-it-possible-to-run-ssh-copy-id-on-port-other-than-22)