# How to back up to a FreeNAS box?

Tags: deja-dup, smb

I have a FreeNAS box running 8.3, with a password protected SMB share. How would I set up deja dup to work with that share? I can switch to an AFP or NFS share, if need be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also have a FreeNAS system on my network, and I used the built-in Ubuntu backup (deja-dup) to back up to the FreeNAS via SSH. (I tried using SMB too, but I couldn't get it to work. This workaround may work for you.)

First, **I added a new user to FreeNAS** just for backing up Ubuntu. You can add this user via the FreeNAS administration GUI. Since I just need this user to do the one thing, I just named the new FreeNAS user the name of my test machine. If you need a step-by-step on how to do this, please check here: http://doc.freenas.org/index.php/Users

Second, **I created a ZFS Dataset where the backup will happen**. Again, I just named it after the machine. Here is more info on how to create a ZFS Dataset: http://doc.freenas.org/index.php/Volumes#Creating_ZFS_Datasets - I set a cap on the space available to that dataset (twice the size of the hard drive should be more than I'll ever need, but your mileage may vary). After that, **I changed permissions so that the new user is the owner of this ZFS Dataset.**

Then, **I generated an SSH key on my Ubuntu machine**. This Ask Ubuntu thread shows how in great detail: [How can I set up password-less SSH login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46930/how-can-i-set-up-password-less-ssh-login) - I didn't set a password for my key, because I don't think deja dup can handle that.

Next, I **copied the SSH public key into the appropriate box in the FreeNAS User control panel** for that user. Make sure your public and private keys are in your /home/(username)/.ssh/ directory on your Ubuntu machine. **At the same time, I also set the ZFS Dataset I created as this user's home directory.**

Finally, I set up the backup settings. Here's how my settings look:

> Backup location: SSH (available in the dropdown menu)
>
> Server: 192.168.x.x (type in the IP address of your FreeNAS device)
>
> Folder: /mnt/(Pool)/(ZFS Dataset) (Use the full path of the ZFS Dataset you created.)
>
> Username: (use the username you set up **in FreeNAS**)

Test it by trying to "Back Up Now". If you want it to back up automatically, don't set a password for the back-up. Finally, to schedule the backup to repeat, set the frequency on the "Schedule" tab in DejaDup and turn Automatic Backups to "On" in the Overview tab.

If for some reason it doesn't work, double-check your:

- SSH private key is in the correct location on Ubuntu
- SSH public key is in the correct location on FreeNAS
- FreeNAS user has the correct permissions for the ZFS dataset

I took screenshots, and I have more links to stuff, but it seems like this I'm not allowed to add more with limited reputation. I'll see if someone else can try to add them. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

I don't know this box but I suggest nfs if you back up from Linux, http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2104468

Comment: I understand that NFS probably works better for linux, but I'd rather not need to script the backup, and instead, use the gui (although all linux guis have failed me (crash, doesn't work, etc) all too many times to count)