# Deja Dup does not ask for password for FTP, CIFS, WebDAV or SSH

Tags: backup, password, ftp, deja-dup, nas

I'd like to backup my $HOME to my local NAS using CIFS ("Samba", "Windows"), WebDAV, SSH or FTP. I don't care which one (or should I care? My NAS (Synology DS212) supports all).

I've made somce [screenshots](http://wir.myds.me/photo/photo_thumb.php?dir=53637265656e73686f74732f44c3a96ac3a0204475702050726f626c656d73) available; they might help to understand what I did. At least I hope so… ☺

In the Déjà Dup settings, I entered the details as shown on the screenshot; it translates to the following custom location: `ftp://a@172.17.2.3:21/home/Sicherung/DejaDup`

When I then try to start a backup, I just see a screen which says:

> Backup location not available
>
> Waiting for a network connection …

What I'm missing is the prompt for the password. Is that the issue? The directory `/home/Sicherung/DejaDup` exists on my local FTP server `172.17.2.3` for my user `a`; see this screenshot of the FTP session on [my pictures](http://wir.myds.me/photo/photo_thumb.php?dir=53637265656e73686f74732f44c3a96ac3a0204475702050726f626c656d73).

Thanks,
Alexander

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, if your backup location requires a password, Deja Dup has no way to get the user to supply that password. If you need to connect securely, you could set up SSH key authentication if your NAS supports that. This walks through how to do that if you need that: [How can I set up password-less SSH login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46930/how-can-i-set-up-password-less-ssh-login)

I back up via SSH in Deja-Dup. I've talked about how here: https://askubuntu.com/a/346005/103537 While those instructions are pretty particular to FreeNAS, something similar could work for your NAS.

Otherwise, you could try setting up a location on your NAS that does not require a password.

Comment: "If there's anything you don't want protected behind a password it's a copy of all your most valued data" — Deja Dup