# SSH for ubuntu touch

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

For some reason, while I am trying to connect to SSH on my Nexus 7 2013 I keep getting this error message:

```
Permission denied(publickey)
```

Can someone explain how to properly setup SSH for Ubuntu touch?

Comment: Have you setup the server for public key authentication yourself? If not have a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/46930/how-can-i-set-up-password-less-ssh-login

Comment: This needs Ubuntu Touch specific details, due to the *tidy-up* of security and settings on Ubuntu Touch **14.10 BETA** (*Utopic*). First, SSH needs to be enabled (on device), you need to have created a public key (on workstation), and you need to transfer this to the device.

Comment: The **Ubuntu Touch specific details** are explained in [SSH Ubuntu Touch](http://askubuntu.com/questions/601910/ssh-ubuntu-touch/653595#653595) as a working solution. This is, as always with password-less authentication, after placing a `/home/phablet/.ssh/authorized_keys` file (with a public key of the PC you're using to access the Ubuntu Touch device) on your device. The verbose option in `ssh -v phablet@<ip-address>` helps with debugging in the end, when you still have problems to connect / log in.