# How to add new private key (OpenSSH) with multiple identities?

Tags: server, ssh, encryption

I have generated pair of both public and private key for one remote host. Now I want to add another private key in open format to connect via ssh to second remote host, but ssh denies connection with "Bad passphrase" when I want to add key with `ssh-add "key_name"`. I only have private key, which in Putty on Windows machine works fine. I only have two files in my `/home/user/.ssh` directory:

```
id_dsa
known_hosts
```

Comment: You don't need to add a new private key. You need one private key (that you have already generated). The public key (of that private-public pair) can be sent to as many remote hosts as you want. That's why it is "public". See [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/589467/multiple-users-private-public-keys/589505#589505)

Comment: On my virtual machine key is working, on my host keeps hitting me with bad passphrase.

Answer (score 0):

Easy as pie.

Simply go to the `.ssh` folder in your `home` and add the file `config`

```
nano /home/${USER}/.ssh/config
```

and add the following lines e.g.

```
Host duck-a-rub
HostName mail.man.com OR <IP-Address>
User rubberduck
Port 223
IdentityFile /full/path/to/keys/rubberduck_id_dsa
```

save the file and give it a try.

```
ssh duck-a-rub
```

HTH,
s1mmel

Comment: ah, add as many hosts as you like :)