# is it possible to rsync to another server using crontab?

Tags: server, ssh, backup, cron, rsync

Hi there is a bunch of videos and resources on how to rsync locally `rsync /home/user1 /home/user2/backup`, but i haven't found any tutorials on rsync crontab to another server

pretty much, i use `crontab -e`
and i have a script i run from `rsynch.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
rsync -xza /home/willchap  willchap@server02:/home/willchap/backup
```

it will work fine without crontab, the problem is, i am guessing crontab fails because it is asking for a password

what are my options here?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/46930/how-can-i-set-up-password-less-ssh-login

Answer (score 4):

The best option, if you can, is to set up key-based SSH authentication on the remote server, and use a key with no passphrase on the client.  This will allow the SSH connection, which rsync uses when you use that `[user@]server:path` notation, to happen without prompting for a password.

Ubuntu documentation for doing this is at:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys#Key-Based_SSH_Logins

Once set up, try to SSH to the remote server from and to the same accounts that rsync would use, and see if it asks for a password.  If it doesn't, it's set up correctly.

Comment: If you refer to this Q&A, https://askubuntu.com/questions/939677/ubuntu-16-04-rsync-via-ssh-prompts-me-for-password-how-to-make-it-a-cron-job, it turns out that in addition to setting this up it is also necessary to explicitly send the public key with the actual rsync command, also.

Comment: As part of the setup, you place the public key of the client into the authorized_keys file on the server, but this is a one-time operation only, after which rsync over SSH will just work as normal without prompting for a password.

Answer (score 0):

actually, yes it is possible.

do your normal rsyncscript.sh
you will need to generate keys using the command ssh-keygen

in your home directory, go to .ssh/id_rsa.pub and copy that into the other servers /authorized_keys file

Comment: While your answer is technically correct, it would be better if you could flesh it out and show the steps:  ssh-keygen, ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh.id_rsa.pub <target> and all that.  It is just a two-step process for each system.