# How to ssh using perl scipt,run a command, and return the output...?

Tags: command-line, ssh, perl

As clearly explained in the question, kindly give me an option to ssh to a machine using perl script, run a few script lines there, and return the output to the source machine.

Found out a few docs online on this, but nothing seems to be informative/clear.

Please help.

Comment: What didn't Googling "perl ssh" answer? It'll give you this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848725/how-can-i-ssh-inside-a-perl-script What more do you need?

Comment: I  had seen these answers but still, I am afraid, I cannot figure-out how can I run a command remotely and take the output back into the current running script to complete the execution. Please specify that too....!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree that the current examples look helpful but don't always work! My previous examples are included in that. I'm not a Perl expert at all but I've cobbled the following together and it works for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

use Net::SSH2;

my $ssh2 = Net::SSH2->new();
$ssh2->connect('tank') or die $!;
my $auth = $ssh2->auth_publickey(
    'oli',
    '/home/oli/.ssh/id_rsa'
);

my $chan2 = $ssh2->channel();
$chan2->blocking(1);

# This is where we send the command and read the response
$chan2->exec("uname -a\n");
print "$_" while <$chan2>;

$chan2->close;
```

Obviously you'll want to change the hostname, username and location of your RSA/DSA/etc key. Additionally, you'll need the compat library to make this work well on Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install libnet-openssh-compat-perl
```

And finally —assuming you call it `script.pl`— call it like so:

```
perl -MNet::OpenSSH::Compat=Net::SSH2 script.pl
```

Answer (score 2):

You could always just run a system call from within your shell script. As long as you can ssh from the shell, you don't need to install anything:

```
perl -e '$r=`ssh user\@host hostname`; print "Remote host:$r"'
```

If you need to run this automatically, you have a few options:

1. Do it cleanly as described in [Oli's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/634105/85695).
2. Set up [passwordless, key-based ssh authentication](https://askubuntu.com/q/46930/85695).
3. Use `sshpass`

   First, install it from the repositories:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install sshpass
   ```

   Then run this:

   ```
   perl -e '$r=`sshpass -p "password" ssh user\@host hostname`; print "Remote host:$r"'
   ```

Comment: Works, but this command returns with a password request. The program should be able to be ran in a cron job without a user inputting the password manually. Can this be done..?

Comment: @kiranbbnl yes, see updated answer.

Comment: Net::SSH supports keyfiles so using one directly would be preferable to embedding a password somewhere IMO. I've added another chunk to my answer.

Comment: @terdon : perl -e '$r=ssh pass -p "AcN1234" ssh admin\@172.20.20.12 sysserver; print "Remote host:$r"' This is also not working.. Is there any mistake in the command that I had typed..? –

Comment: @kiranbbnl yes, you forgot the backticks, those are needed: `perl -e '$r=\`ssh pass -p "AcN1234" ssh admin\@172.20.20.12 sysserver\`; print "Remote host:$r"' `

Comment: @Oli absolutely, that's why my 1st solution was to use yours :).

Comment: i didnt miss that... the backticks were hidden by the webpage while pasting..!! i didnt miss that out..! :)

Comment: @kiranbbnl you added a space between ssh and pass. `sshpass` is a program, you need to use the exact name.