# How do I copy the contents of user/.ssh/known_hosts to the same file under root?

Tags: ssh, root

I am trying to accomplish passwordless ssh-ing from `root`. To be clear, I want to log in from the local machine at `root` to a `/home/user` folder on remote. Have established the connection between user@local to user@remote, but can't figure out how to allow root to connect.

Comment: You reall do not need to do that as host will be added if you run ssh are root. To copy the file `cp ~user/.ssh/.known_hosts /root/.ssh`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I set up password-less SSH login?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/46930/how-can-i-set-up-password-less-ssh-login) ....replace the user to `root`..

Comment: Can not recommend connecting (as **root**) over SSH. *You may also be having issues with SSH config settings that prevent this type of access.* If you can explain why you really need this, I may be able to help.

Comment: Need to passively move regularly generated files to another computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, known_hosts is not the file that you want to copy. That is just a list of all the systems that have been connected to to check if the system might have changed or a man-in-the-middle attack is being attempted.

For password less connections, you need a id_rsa file in .ssh folder.
You can copy the file and make sure is has the correct permissions. 600 for the file

or better, create a new key for root to use.
sudo up to root. create the key and then copy the id_rsa.pub contents to the authorized_keys on the remote system. there are steps in the link below.

`ssh-keygen -t rsa`

[ssh - without password](http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html)

Or create your key as Root then use `ssh-copy-id` command, it will add the files where they need to be.
`ssh-copy-id user@hostname.example.com`

Comment: I did create a new key under root and copied it to remote, but the script calling ssh to the remote asks for the passphrase each iteration. How do I avoid this? Just skip the passphrase on the root keyset?

Comment: Yes. you can skip the passphrase part.

Comment: Is the passphrase a 'paranoid' level of security? I don't want to skimp on useful levels of security.

Comment: It is not really a paranoid level of security, as you just replaced your password with a txt file, that if someone gets access on the system can then access to all other systesms. With ssh-add and ssh-agent, you can use the passphrase to unlock the authentication keys so not everyone can use them, but you will only have to enter it one time.

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases/

Comment: so how do i enter my passphrase the one time if it's an autostart root login?

Comment: That I am unsure of how to do. except in plain text format. normally you should never run as root. unless absolutely necessary. why not create a user with appropriate permissions on both systems. and use that user instead of root.