# Can't connect to ubuntu 14.04 from android using ssh

Tags: networking, server, ssh, android, authentication

I have a laptop, a desktop and an android phone(Moto G) connected to the same wifi network at home.
I had installed openssh-server on my laptop and desktop and could connect between them using ssh. I also could connect to them from my phone using ConnectBot.

To avoid entering the password when connecting from the desktop to the laptop, I followed the steps in this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/46935/411123 for key-based authentication. I can now connect from my desktop to the laptop without using a password but when I try to connect to my laptop using ConnectBot, I get the error: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host).
Though I can still connect to my desktop using ConnectBot.
How can I connect to my laptop from my phone? Does key based authentication from one client disable password authentication from other clients?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried again and now I can connect to my laptop from my phone using ssh. Most probably there was a network problem.