# How to stream my logkeys.log to another server?

Tags: log, logs

I have installed "logkeys" in my server. Now I want the log file (that is "logkeys.log") generated in that server to be streamed to another machine at specific timings.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

One very simple way would be to allow the destination (server B) to do a [password-less SSH](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46930/how-can-i-set-up-password-less-ssh-login) (or SFTP) connection to server A (where the file resides) and then create a cron job on server B that would copy the file at certain time intervals, by invoking scp (the syntax would be similar to: `scp serverA:/path/to/logkeys.sys /path/to/destination`

Password-less connection means, of course, using keys :-)