# Multiple scp commands in bash script, but entering password only once

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, ssh, scp

I currently use a bash script in the following format to update local data with remote one:

```
usr=$1
scp -P 4444 -r $usr@some.other.machine.at:/some/folder/*Tools /home/localUser/someFolder/
scp -P 4444 -r $usr@some.other.machine.at:/some/folder/*.project /home/localUser/someFolder/
```

i.e., I want to copy each folder (its content and subfolders) that ends with *Tools* and to copy each file that ends with *.project* from `/some/folder/` (okay, I would not need -r here) at the remote machine into my local folder `/home/localUser/someFolder/`.

(Not sure if this is important, I run this script with `bash myScript.sh`)

Currently, I have to enter the remote user's password two times, once per `scp` command. Is there a way so that the password has to be entered only one time?

Comment: Why are you using passwords in the first place, if you want to script it? Set up passwordless SSH: http://askubuntu.com/q/46930/158442

Comment: @muru: I will just look into this, yet I would be still interested if there is some way to overcome the multiple password entering if passwordless SSH is not set up.

Comment: Unlike sudo, etc. SSH doesn't do credential caching. You could use `sshpass` to automate entering the password, but I don't see the point of doing that over setting up keys.

Comment: I followed your guide in the first comment, now it works without password. I always thought that ssh would have to be configured in some special way on the server to enable this (I don't have priviliges to change something on the server), but I have to admit that I never looked into setting up ssh in detail.
Also thanks for the info with sshpass, I will probably look into it additionally just for learning :)

Comment: No, default ssh server configurations always allow key-based login. On the other hand, the SSH server can be configured to *only* allow key-based login, and not allow password-based login at all.

Comment: The question makes a lot of sense however, if passwordless ssh is set up, but the rsa file is encrypted with a password locally. Then again, for each command, a password needs to be entered.