# how to turn off password-less login for ssh?

Tags: server, ssh, login, password

I had setup password-less SSH login from my desktop to my laptop following the steps [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/46935/411123). Now I want to turn off the password-less login so that when I ssh from my desktop to my laptop, it will ask for the password. How do I do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Disable pubkey authentication on the client where you don't want to use it.

```
ssh -o PubkeyAuthentication=no your_host
```

or in your `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host your_host
  PubkeyAuthentication no
```

If you want to remove the public key from the server, you need to remove the appropriate line from `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on server.

Comment: Can the public key from the server be deleted?

Comment: Yes. You will remove it the opposite way as you added it there. The file is `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Answer (score 1):

As

```
ssh -o PubkeyAuthentication=no your_host
```

can easily be reverted by anyone who has access to the client to login to your laptob without needing a password at all, it may be a better choice to use a password encrypted private-key for those destinations, where you want to be asked for a password before login.

Comment: Or remote the key entirely. But it is not clear what is the OP intention.

Comment: Can the public key on the laptop(the host) be deleted?

Comment: yes, it can. the public keys are stored on the host in the file $HOME/.ssh/allowed_keys - one key each line.