# Auto-input help

Tags: bash, scp

My end goal is to create an alias for scp:

First, I need a way of inputting the remote users' password automatically for this to be a single input command. Security isn't a big deal with this, so I' happy to have the password in a text file. I've tried the following, but there all still prompt for input:

```
scp  from/path usr:w.x.y.z:to/path <<< "passwd"

echo "passwd" | scp  from/path usr:w.x.y.z:to/path

printf "passwd\n" | scp  from/path usr:w.x.y.z:to/path
```

All still prompt me for input.

Once I've figured that out, I'm going to run:

```
echo 'alias pts=" fixed command above"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you're going wrong is assuming `scp` reads passwords from standard input - AFAIK it doesn't. You have a number of options:

1. set up key-based authentication, using a key with an empty passphrase - see [How can I set up password-less SSH login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46930/how-can-i-set-up-password-less-ssh-login)
2. use the `sshpass` utility (available from the repository)
3. script the password interaction using `expect`

Comment: option 1 worked perfectly. Thank you!