# SSH asking password each time i run start-all.sh for hadoop

Tags: ssh, hadoop

I have installed Hadoop on following path:

```
/opt/hadoop
```

Also installed `openssh-server` with following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server openssh-client
```

After this I created RSA keys with following commands:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -P ""
```

After that i copied to slave system and created copy using:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
sudo chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Everything was working fine with Hadoop and SSH. Suddenly SSH asking for password each and every time I run

```
ssh hduser@MasterNode
```

or

```
/opt/hadoop/sbin/start-all.sh
```

Comment: Try http://askubuntu.com/questions/46930/how-can-i-set-up-password-less-ssh-login

Comment: @Katu i tried all that steps while installing hadoop. the thing is i am using Ubuntu 16.10 version and after couple of restarts that key is not working for hadoop start-all.sh command. my question is how to solve this?

Comment: I have never used hadoop. If you are saying that passwordless ssh works from the terminal but not from hadoop, I can't help. But make sure that when you ssh from the terminal you don't need the password and also that hadoop uses the same user that you do (the user that stores the private key) and not sudo or other.

Comment: Thank you @Katu for your help.. but i need the solution to use hadoop.. if anyone can help please tell me the solution....

Comment: Turn on verbose output for the ssh session handshake - perhaps you can from the output figure out what is going on `ssh -vvv hduser@MasterNode`

Comment: @jhilmer this is also not working, asking for password every time.. can it be related to operating system? i am using ubuntu 16.10... is it stable version?

Comment: i think Ubuntu 16.10 is having that issue with ssh service. after downgrading the Ubuntu 16.10 to 16.04 LTS everything is working fine. does anyone having the solution to resolve ssh issue _"while running hadoop ssh asking for password every time"_ for Ubuntu 16.10