# Use a sudo to mount an external disk on remote device

Tags: 14.04, usb, mount, sudo, remote

I'm currently working on two devices, one testing the other. They are based on beaglebone black, and run under Ubuntu 14.04. My problem is I have to detect and mount a USB external storage on the tested device but from the tester device.

I tried a few commands to avoid entering passwords like

```
sshpass -p <password> ssh aet@192.168.100.200 StrictHostKeyChecking=no "echo gra64nola | sudo -S true mount /dev/sda1/ /media"
```

but when I execute this line, nothing happens on the remote device. I tried a few different versions on this command line, but I'm lost now. I got no idea how to do what I want.

For information I work under node-red and I execute these three command lines to detect and mount the device. The aet@192.168.100.200 is the IP of the tested device. It is connected by ethernet on a common switch with the testing one.

```
sshpass -p <password> ssh aet@192.168.100.200 StrictHostKeyChecking=no "echo gra64nola | sudo -S true mount /dev/sda1/ /media"

sshpass -p <password> ssh aet@192.168.100.200 StrictHostKeyChecking=no "echo gra64nola | sudo -S true umount /media"

sshpass -p <password> ssh aet@192.168.100.200 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no "echo gra64nola |sudo -S find /media/FINDME.txt"
```

the third one is used to find a file to check if USB port of device works. I don't want anybody to do my whole job, but would you please know how to mount this external disk please ?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You may try ssh key authentication.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to ubuntu. I use this line a bit before to send audio files `ssh-keygen -f /root/.ssh/known_hosts -R ${REMOTE_HOST} > /dev/null`. Is that what you mean ?

Comment: Remote host is just an inserted IP and I use a scp after this line

Comment: `$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 1024 -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa` -> copy key to remote host `$ ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub aet@192.168.100.200` and then try connect without password `$ ssh aet@192.168.100.200`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sudo -S true mount /dev/sda1/ /media
```

`true` usually ignores any arguments passed to it, so the `mount ...` part is completely ignored. If you want to run the `mount` command, don't use `true`. Just do:

```
sudo -S mount /dev/sda1/ /media
```

Also look into:

- [How do I run specific sudo commands without a password?](https://askubuntu.com/q/159007/158442)
- [How can I set up password-less SSH login?](https://askubuntu.com/q/46930/158442)

Comment: Thanks ! I hadn't got that true was deleting my command. Thank you very much, you save a newbie...