# run netcat on crontab

Tags: files, directory, cron, copy, netcat

I have 2 systems

```
1: 192.168.0.31 
2: 192.168.0.32
```

From system 1 terminal I executed below command

```
tar -zcf - test | pv | nc -l -p 5555 -q 5
```

From system 2 terminal I executed below command

```
nc 192.168.0.31 5555 | pv | tar -zxf -
```

Now full test folder with all containing files copied to system 2

How can I to schedule both commands using `crontab` or something else?

Comment: You should really do that using SCP, doing this with NC is very unsecure as there is no authentication or encryption whatsoever involved.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you would like to make a backup/copy of data in one computer into another.

A very simple and secure solution might be using `scp` which is based on `ssh`.

`scp` sample command might look like:

```
scp -r /path/to/local/folder user@remotehost:/path/to/remote/folder
```

e.g.

- Assuming that:

  - your username is `shaji`
  - You wan to copy files from `192.168.0.31` `/home/shaji`
  - To `192.168.0.32` into folder `/backup/shaji/backup`
- You should run the following command on `192.168.0.31`:

  `scp -r /home/shaji shaji@192.168.0.32:/home/shaji/backup`

Note: You can run the `scp command` using `crontab`

> [man scp](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/scp.1.html)
>
> scp — secure copy (remote file copy program)
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> ```
>  scp copies files between hosts on a network.  It uses ssh(1) for data
>  transfer, and uses the same authentication and provides the same security
>  as ssh(1).  Unlike rcp(1), scp will ask for passwords or passphrases if
>  they are needed for authentication.
>
>  File names may contain a user and host specification to indicate that the
>  file is to be copied to/from that host.  Local file names can be made
>  explicit using absolute or relative pathnames to avoid scp treating file
>  names containing ‘:’ as host specifiers.  Copies between two remote hosts
>  are also permitted.
>
>  -r      Recursively copy entire directories.  Note that scp follows
>          symbolic links encountered in the tree traversal.
> ```

There are some pre-requites:

- `sshd` should run on the remote host
- Setting password-less ssh access to remote host - [see askubuntu Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/q/46930/544264)

Comment: I tried to run command but permission denied.

Comment: I appreciate your help please confirm that command should be run on system1 or system2

Comment: Now I tested the command on system 1 and its working fine, files from system1 are copying to system2. Is there any simple way to make it password less?

Comment: @shaji - as mentioned in the link of [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/q/46930/544264) - you should execute `ssh-keygen` followed by `ssh-copy-id user@host` - please review this Q&A

Comment: @shaji - did my answer solve your problem?

Comment: Yes I managed it as you suggested thank you so much @Yaron

Comment: @shaji - if my answer solve your problem please accept it