# Shell script that fetches file with SCP

Tags: command-line

I want to build a shell script that runs daily and fethces a file from another server using SCP command.

The problem is that when i enter this command in terminal it asks me for password.

a) How can a shells script enter password?

b) Is it really a good idea to store the password in a shell script?

Command example:

```
scp -r myUser@myServer:/local/java/log/archive/2018/02/16/log.2018-02-16.gz ~/Temp/
```

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/85655/158442 and comments for entering passwords in a shell script

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First step : setting a password-less SSH access (via ssh-keygen) :

Run `ssh-keygen` (you end up with 2 files : id_rsa and id_rsa.pub, one is your .pub public key to share with the world, the other your private key).
Then run `ssh-copy-id myUser@myServer`. Just type your password when prompted and you're now able to SSH without having to type your password for myUser@myServer.

Second step : automated daily scp :

Type `crontab -e`, pick your favorite editor and add a line at the bottom of the file : `0 0 * * * scp -r myUser@myServer:/local/java/log/archive/2018/02/16/log.2018-02-16.gz ~/Temp/` save and... Voilà!
(you can use a `@daily scp (...)` crontab entry, wich is basicaly the same as 0 0 * * *)

See Anacron ([Job scheduling using crontab, what will happen when computer is shutdown during that time?](https://serverfault.com/a/52338)) for managing Cron task when you computer is down.