# SSH without password with non-default identity file location

Tags: command-line, server, ssh, password

As part of a startup script I have to automatically open several gnome-terminal windows, one of those terminals automatically send:

```
ssh user@192.168.1.3
```

The limitation with this is that I still need to type a password to complete the SSH connection.

What I want to do is for my script to initiate the command and complete the connection. To that extent, I attempted to follow the instructions as outlined in the accepted answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46930/how-can-i-set-up-password-less-ssh-login).

From the system I wish to connect from, I ran:

```
ssh-keygen
Enter file in which to save the key: /home/user/ssh/keys/server1key
```

It then prompted me to enter a passphrase. I left this empty, as I wasn't sure what it would be for, so I assumed setting one would require unlocking it with said passphrase each time I'd use it.

Continuing with the instructions linked above, I then ran and received the following:

```
ssh-copy-id user@IP
ERROR: No identities found
```

A quick search revealed that I needed to specify the location of the key, as it was not in the default save location, so I fixed that:

```
ssh-copy-id -i /home/user/ssh/keys/server1key.pub user@192.168.1.3
```

After asking for the server's password, it successfully added the key. However, upon attempting to log in with "ssh user@IP", I was still prompted for the password.

As far as I'm aware, I followed the linked instructions correctly, so either I'm missing something, or perhaps an existing configuration is preventing me for getting this to work?

Both systems use 18.04 and openssh.

Comment: So I need to specify the location of the .pub file when sending the SSH command?

Comment: I've got a bit of a different way of organising my files, hence the non-default locations, but you guys have helped greatly. Thanks. Feel free to make it an answer I can accept.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It fails for the same reason that `ssh-copy-id` failed the first time - i.e. because you have chosen a non-default location for the identity file.

You can resolve it in the same way, by adding `-i /home/user/ssh/keys/server1key` to your `ssh` command - note that the client side needs the location of the **private** key file.

From `man ssh`

```
 -i identity_file
         Selects a file from which the identity (private key) for public
         key authentication is read.  The default is ~/.ssh/identity for
         protocol version 1, and ~/.ssh/id_dsa, ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa,
         ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 and ~/.ssh/id_rsa for protocol version 2.
```

Alternatively, you may wish to create a `~/.ssh/config` file entry for the host along the lines of

```
Host            somename
Hostname        192.168.1.3
User            user
IdentityFile    /home/user/ssh/keys/server1key
```

Comment: I always assumed that the config file required indentation - I see that's not the case. Intruiging.

Comment: Anyone using OpenSSH should have a `~/.ssh/config`, otherwise OpenSSH uses the system wide default `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`.  In case anyone finds it helpful, I uploaded a [pre-built ssh_config](https://github.com/JW0914/Wikis/blob/master/Scripts%2BConfigs/OpenSSH/BSD-Linux/config) to my GitHub a while back as a starting point for users who may not have time to read the [ssh_config man page](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config)

Comment: @JW0914 that's only half true: individual values in `~/.ssh/config` will override those of the global `ssh_config`, but just having the file will not disable the system wide configuration.

Comment: @SebastianStark Perhaps you misread my comment, as I never stated it would disable the system wide configuration.  What I stated was 100% factually accurate.

Answer (score 3):

Another reason that `ssh-copy-id` fails is that the key hasn't been added to the SSH agent.

First, check and start if `ssh-agent` is running:

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
```

If you get in process ID, you can add your key:

```
ssh-add -k /home/user/ssh/keys/server1key
```

With `-k` you add the key to the keychain.

Check if keys are added with:

```
ssh-add -l
```

`ssh-copy-id` should be working now.

Answer (score -1):

Hope this will work for you.. "sshpass -p yourpassword" it will automatically login to remote host.

[root@localhost .ssh]# sshpass -p password123 ssh -l root localhost

Answer (score -1):

Just execute 2 commands:

```
ssh-keygen
ssh-copy-id
```

Long answer:

```
user@ip:~$ ssh-keygen
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa): temp_file
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in stemp.
Your public key has been saved in stemp.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:5**M user@ip
The key's randomart image is:
+---[RSA 2048]----+
|  ...            |
| ...             |
| ..              |
| ..+.    o .     |
|                 |
|    B            |
|                 |
|=      *         |
|=+   o .         |
+----[SHA256]-----+
```

And then:

```
user@ip:~$ ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub ipDestination -p portDest
```