# How to upload files to sftp-server with public key via terminal on ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, sftp, curl

i´m an ubuntu beginner and i´d like to upload a .csv file to an sftp-folder on a remote machine every night via cronjob.

Because i´m building the csv with R, i thought of uploading the file with the RCurl-package, but here i´m getting the error-message that

```
* Protocol "sftp" not supported or disabled in libcurl
* Closing connection -1
Fehler in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  Protocol "sftp" not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

And it´s true:

```
~$ curl -V
curl 7.58.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.58.0 OpenSSL/1.1.0g zlib/1.2.11 libidn2/2.0.4 libpsl/0.19.1 (+libidn2/2.0.4) nghttp2/1.30.0 librtmp/2.3
Release-Date: 2018-01-24
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS IDN IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP HTTP2 UnixSockets HTTPS-proxy PSL
```

I couldn´t find the steps how i add the sftp protocol to curl. I´ve google a lot and did not find a working solution. I would be very glad if you could point me to a solution to my problem. I don´t need to use RCurl - i just want a way to transfer my files to the sftp folder, but i´m not familiar enough with ubuntu yet... Thank you!

Comment: Does R have a way of running external commands? Then use that to run `scp some-file.csv server:some-folder`

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. I´ve generated a public key and they added it to their server. How can i use this key? I´ve not found anything in http://www.hypexr.org/linux_scp_help.php // PS: yes, you can just write system("terminalcode") in R.

Comment: `scp` should automatically pick up your key unless it's in an unusual location. Did you do something similar to https://askubuntu.com/questions/46930/how-can-i-set-up-password-less-ssh-login?