# Passwordless SSH

Tags: 18.04, permissions, root, openssh

Can we set up Passwordless SSH in Ubuntu (18.04) without root privileges? Is there any way to access files in /etc directory without root permissions? (I need to be able to set up Passwordless SSH between non-root users from between a local and remote system, but I don't have the root privileges on either system)

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Do you have an account in the remote computer you want to `ssh` into? Can you use `ssh` with password? Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1119936/edit) your question and add more information about your setup.

Comment: I need to be able to set up Passwordless SSH between non-root users from between a local and remote system, but I don't have the root privileges on either system.

Comment: Assuming `ssh` is "properly" setup by whoever has root privileges, You can setup password less login for yourself. This question [How can I set up password less ssh login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46930/how-can-i-set-up-password-less-ssh-login) has been already answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your ssh server already has the publickey authentication method enabled, all you need to do is to append your own public key to the `.ssh/authorized_keys` file in the home directory of your server user. No further administrative configuration required for that.

And configuration files in `/etc` are normally all owned by the root user and not writable by anyone else, you can not bypass that as regular user without `sudo`. Otherwise that would be a security threat.