# Changed root password by sudo passwd root but I can not login with root login

Tags: server, sudo, password, root

Hei,
The title is self-explaining.

I installed Ubuntu Server 18.04.03 LTS + Canonical Live Patch.
I logged it with my username created during installation and run `sudo passwd root` and changed root account password, but I can not login into my server directly with root account.

Why?

Comment: Remote root password login is disabled to help hackers.

Comment: If you are logging in remotely, say, over SSH, root login is disabled by default.  How are you logging in, SSH?

Comment: It works over TTY but not SSH, how to allow root login over SSH temporarily (to very first basic config)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For *temporary* access, you need to still update the configurations.

In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, there is a line that looks something like this:

```
#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
```

This is the *Default* which is why it's commented out, meaning you need SSH keys installed/enabled to login to the `root` account directly.

You can *uncomment* this and allow root login by changing this to:

```
PermitRootLogin yes
```

***HOWEVER***, this is very dangerous because it allows bots and other attackers to attempt bruteforcing the login.  So if you *absolutely must* have root login, only enable this for a VERY short time, then set the thing back to either...

```
PermitRootLOgin prohibit-password
```

... or ...

```
PermitRootLogin no
```

... for security reasons.

If you intend to login to root directly in the future, though, then I strongly suggest you go the key authentication route if you intend to login to `root` directly, or just use `sudo` for every command you want to run as root on your standard user, rather than changing the security settings.

(I'm an IT Security guy, this suggestion is kind of mandatory from guys like me.)

Comment: Thanks!
It worked.

Can you give me some idea on "key authentication route"?

Comment: @NimaMasalegooha You'll want to look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/46930/how-can-i-set-up-password-less-ssh-login