# How do you add the password into ~/.ssh/config file for custom ssh connections

Tags: command-line, server, ssh, password

I have multiple ssh connections I want to add to the config file in the `.ssh` directory, but it seems the password field is not catered for. Below is the error I get:

[image: console error after running ssh]

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: You're supposed to use SSH keys instead

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I set up password-less SSH login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46930/how-can-i-set-up-password-less-ssh-login)

Answer (score 2):

There is no way for providing password in ssh config.

You should use [ssh keys](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/key/) instead.

But, if you would like to work around it, keep in mind that saving passwords in plain text is insecure.

Simple workaround would be creating a ssh wrapper with sshpass on top.

Install sshpass first:

```
sudo apt install sshpass
```

Prepare a bash script for a wrapper:

```
touch $HOME/.ssh/sshp.sh
chmod 700 $HOME/.ssh/sshp.sh
```

Paste this code into *$HOME/.ssh/sshp.sh*

> ```
> #!/bin/bash
>
> SSH_HOST=$1
>
> if [[ ! "$SSH_HOST" ]]; then echo "provide ssh_host as first argument"
> ; exit 1 ; fi
>
> sshpass -p "$(cat $HOME/.ssh/passwords/$SSH_HOST)" ssh $SSH_HOST
> ```

Edit ~/.bashrc and add:

```
alias sshp='$HOME/.ssh/sshp.sh'
```

Then type:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Next, save passwords for your hosts like this:

```
mkdir $HOME/.ssh/passwords
chmod 700 $HOME/.ssh/passwords
echo -n "password" > $HOME/.ssh/passwords/EXAMPLEHOST1
echo -n "password" > $HOME/.ssh/passwords/EXAMPLEHOST2
echo -n "password" > $HOME/.ssh/passwords/EXAMPLEHOST3
```

Clean current bash history once you've saved your passwords.

```
history -c
```

And use sshp alias instead ssh to connect to your server:

```
sshp EXAMPLEHOST1
```

Comment: Use `sshpass -f` instead of `-p`