# ssh root password

Tags: ssh, root

How can I get the root password, I'm trying to login in cmd with the command ssh root@localhost and I don't know what type of password I should use.
The server is a linux vps. My system is Windows 10.

Comment: Root login with password is disabled by default. You should instead set up login with SSH keypair if you need to login as root.

Comment: Ubuntu doesn't allow `root` logins. We use `sudo` after logging in as a regular user.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You *very likely* have [an XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/1081494). While it is technically possible to set up Ubuntu to log in as the root user (if you know what you're doing), it isn't generally recommended. You *definently* don't want a publicly-accessible computer (or VPS) to have root password login enabled over SSH.

Some VPS providers of some OS's do root login by default, but even there, I'd suggest setting up a normal user account to use unless you have a reason for root.

If you *really* need to login as root, and not use `sudo`, please use [SSH key login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46930/how-can-i-set-up-password-less-ssh-login). Ideally, and this isn't always possible (and if you do it wrong, you can get locked out of your system), but if you can, also try to have it be SSH-keys *only* so you can't login with a password at all.

Side note: if you're on a Windows computer trying to SSH to a cloud VPS, you'll want something like `ssh username@1.1.1.1` (but with your IP address). Or, if you have a DNS A record pointing to your VPS, you could do `ssh username@example.com` (but with your domain). The latter option may not work if you have a caching proxy for all requests to that domain. Doing `ssh username@localhost` from Windows will try to SSH into Windows itself, which isn't likely to be what you want.